# Programacion Orientada a Objetos. Clase creada que no funciona

Tags: java, poo

Buen día gente, Tengo una duda en mi programa de JAVA que debe ser orientado a objetos.

El ejercicio consta de hacer como una simulación de búsqueda para perros perdidos, tengo un amigo que tiene un capital inicial que se da de forma aleatoria. Lo que deseaba hacer es generar ese capital, luego en la clase principal hacer una opción en el menú que me permita ver cuanto tengo al inicio, sin embargo no tira errores de compilación, solo de sintaxis pero no sale el resultado del capital inicial. me podrían ayudar? adjunto mi código:

```java
import java.util.Random;
public class Amigo {
    private Random rand;
    int dinero_inicial;

Amigo(){
    this.rand = new Random();
    this.dinero_inicial = rand.nextInt() * (int)(1000);//rango de 1 a 1000

}
public int CapitalInicial(){
    return this.dinero_inicial;
}
}
```

La anterior es la clase del objeto, y a continuación presento mi código para la clase principal

```java
public class BuscadorPerritos{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int navegar_menu;
        boolean salir_menu = false;
        Amigo amigo = new Amigo();
        Perro perro = new Perro();

    while(!salir_menu){
        System.out.println("1.Generar un nuevo amigo que ayudar");
        System.out.println("2.Generar un nuevo perro que buscar");
        System.out.println("3.Ver capital inicial disponible para buscar al perro");

    try{
        System.out.println("Ingrese una opcion en el menu");
        navegar_menu = scanner.nextInt();

        switch(navegar_menu){
            case 1:
            System.out.println("Se ha generado un nuevo amigo por ayudar");
            break;

            case 2:
            System.out.println("Se ha generado un nuevo perro que buscar");
            break;

            case 3:
            System.out.println("Su dinero inicial es de\n");
            amigo.CapitalInicial();
            break;
            }
        }finally{
            scanner.close();
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Para mostrar texto en la consola debes de utilizar siempre ` System.out.println` con lo que te retorne el método `CapitalInicial`, seria `System.out.println(amigo.CapitalInicial());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está de más tu variable `rand`, si deseas crear números aleatorios, es suficiente con llamas directamente a la clase `Math` sin instanciar debido a que es un final.

```
public class Amigo {    
    int dinero_inicial;

    Amigo(){        
        this.dinero_inicial = (int) (Math.random() * (1000));//rango de 1 a 1000
    }  
}
```

El error en tu clase `BuscadorPerritos`se encuentra en tu menú de opciones, creas un bucle while infinito y dentro del bucle cierras la variable scanner `scanner.close()`, esta linea de código debe estar fuera del while; también en tu opción 3 del switch no estas mostrando el valor del dinero inicial, lo que estas haciendo es llamar a método que se encuentra en la clase `Amigo`

```
public class BuscadorPerritos{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int navegar_menu;
        boolean salir_menu = false;
        Amigo amigo = new Amigo();
        Perro perro = new Perro();

        while(!salir_menu){
            System.out.println("1.Generar un nuevo amigo que ayudar");
            System.out.println("2.Generar un nuevo perro que buscar");
            System.out.println("3.Ver capital inicial disponible para buscar al perro");

            try{
                System.out.println("Ingrese una opcion en el menu");
                //navegar_menu = scanner.nextInt();
                navegar_menu = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());


                switch(navegar_menu){
                    case 1:
                    System.out.println("Se ha generado un nuevo amigo por ayudar");
                    break;

                    case 2:
                    System.out.println("Se ha generado un nuevo perro que buscar");
                    break;

                    case 3:                        
                    System.out.println("Su dinero inicial es de\n"+amigo.dinero_inicial);                    
                    break;
                }
            } catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);

            }
        }
    scanner.close();    
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, me sirvio y resolviste cabal las otras dudas que tenia pero no habia preguntado. Muchas gracias